# Does Dimensional Scramble's teleport take effect before or after triggered actions?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation, triggered-actions

Scenario - A Psion attacks a creature with Dimensional Scramble, doing enough damage to kill the creature.  The creature has an effect which triggers upon the creature's death.

Did the teleport happen before or after the triggered action?

Some relevant bits from Dimensional Scramble's power card, for reference:

> *Your attack causes space to jumble and fragment, scattering creatures into different positions.*
>
> **Hit:** 1d6 + Intelligence modifier damage, and you teleport the target to a square adjacent to the burst.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the trigger in this case is off a target's death, the answer is **before** the death occurs.

The **Hit** line takes effect all at once. Resolve the attack, then deal with the consequences. (You could actually infer from the color text in this case that the damage is *caused by* the teleport, but either way both damage and teleport happen together before anything else.)

If the successful attack had triggered an immediate interrupt, that would have happened before the teleport **and** before the damage.

As noted in the comments by @Pat, effects that are triggered should be understood as immediate reactions unless explicitly stated otherwise. (Or unless that prevents the effect from working: "reroll on a miss" will always interrupt the miss.)

From the *Rules Compendium* pg 197:

> If an effect has a trigger but is
>   neither an immediate action nor an
>   opportunity action, assume that it
>   behaves like an immediate reaction,
>   waiting for its trigger to completely
>   resolve. However, ignore this guideline
>   when the effect has to interrupt its trigger to function.